# Best combination based in rules

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Which combination of five entries has the largest combined scores subject to the condition?

Comment: Hi! Please review [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: I am not sure what kind of algorithm is this and how it would be the correct way of doing it. I am thinking that this is some category of algorithms which this one is achievable for doing it. If you have a similar example or a similar question to point me, I'll be more than happy so I can investigate further.

Comment: if the dataset is not big, picking all possible 5 players and then checking your restrictions would suffice

Comment: Yes I was thinking to sort based on score and then starting with brute force so I can find the ELO but I was wondering if there is a more elegant way of doing it. Some kind of "magic" algorithm and logic behind it.

Comment: `Array.prototype.sort()` and `Array.prototype.filter()` should do the job: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: If the scores are so few, you can group them by score and sort by elo and then pick all possible 5 players with that structure, you would never consider 5 players with score 2 with 3000 elo if there are 5 with score 2 and 2000 elo

Comment: Why delete the question (but it's not been deleted yet)? Why not just edit to clarify a bit. It's basically a good question.

Comment: Well I've got -3 and I couldn't delete it because an answer has been voted. I guess the rest of stackoverflow community don't think it's worth it, so I tried to remove it. Still, I learnt new things, thank you. My solution is pretty close to yours, I've done some additions and it is faster because I tested it with 150 rows and the combination is still slow.

Comment: John, there are a few things to consider before abandoning the question. Firstly, it's basically a good question, one that could benefit others who see it in future. Secondly, those of us who spent time working up answers would not especially like to see the fruits of our work relegated to the dust bin. Lastly, all that is needed is a clarification of the question (which might result in downvotes being removed). You could state the question as follows: "Which combination of five players has the largest combined scores subject to the condition that their combined ELO's does not exceed 11,000?".

Comment: I just noticed that you clarified the question before I submitted my previous comment. I think it's fine now. I suggest you simply roll-back to your previous edit.

Comment: I don't think the problem was the clarification, you and other members understood clearly what I was trying to achieve. I think it is mostly the attitude of other stackoverflow members even from well recognized ones like @t-j-crowder who don't know the answer and they blame the question itself.  I may need to add only easy questions because most members only care for raising fakely their points.

Comment: @TJCrowder and others who voted to close. The OP has edited the question. I believe it now perfectly clear what the OP is trying to do. It certainly cannot be construed as being too broad. I request you and the others consider reopening the question. Others that agree with my request can also vote to reopen. John, you way wish to consider restoring the "Ruby" and "Javascript" tags.

Comment: @TJCrowder and others who voted to close. The OP has edited the question. I believe it now perfectly clear what the OP is trying to do. It certainly cannot be construed as being too broad. I request you and the others consider reopening the question. Others that agree with my request can also vote to reopen. John, you may wish to consider restoring the "Ruby" and "Javascript" tags. Perhaps also consider changing `11.000` to `11000` for those who don't realize that the period is a thousands separator. Hang in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code**

```
def best_five(players, max_elo)
  players.combination(5).with_object({ names:[], tot_scores: -1 }) do |arr, best|
    names, elos, scores = arr.map(&:values).transpose
    best.replace({ names: names, tot_scores: scores.sum }) unless
      elos.sum > max_elo || scores.sum <= best[:tot_scores]
  end
end
```

Here `players` is an array of hashes, each with keys `:name`, `:elo` and `score`, where the value of `:name` is a string and values of the other two keys are integers.

**Example**

```
players =<<_
Derek Aufderhar, 2134, 1
Hadley Kuhn, 2044, 0
Myrtie Lueilwitz, 2207, 2
Mitchell Schiller, 2036, 2
Javier Walter MD, 2485, 4
Waino Leuschke, 2486, 2
Ariel Jacobson, 2015, 3
Melvin Bailey, 2485, 0
Dovie Emmerich, 2383, 4
Adrian Stroman Jr., 2180, 1
Helen Douglas, 2352, 4
Yessenia O’Reilly, 2247, 2
_
```

It is convenient to convert this string to a hash, both to address the current problem and to perform other operations with the data.

```
players_by_name = players.each_line.with_object({}) do |line, h|
  name, elo, score = line.split(',')
  h[name] = { name: name, elo: elo.to_i, score: score.to_i }
end
  #=> {"Derek Aufderhar"  =>{:name=>"Derek Aufderhar",   :elo=>2134, :score=>1},
  #    "Hadley Kuhn"      =>{:name=>"Hadley Kuhn",       :elo=>2044, :score=>0},
  #    ...
  #    "Yessenia O’Reilly"=>{:name=>"Yessenia O’Reilly", :elo=>2247, :score=>2}}
```

We may now compute the best five for `max_elo = 11000`:

```
best = best_five(players_by_name.values, 11000)
  #=> {:names=>["Myrtie Lueilwitz", "Mitchell Schiller", "Ariel Jacobson",
  #             "Dovie Emmerich", "Helen Douglas"],
  #    :tot_scores=>15}
```

To retrieve information for these five players we compute the following:

```
a = players_by_name.values_at(*best[:names])
  #=> [{:name=>"Myrtie Lueilwitz" , :elo=>2207, :score=>2},
  #    {:name=>"Mitchell Schiller", :elo=>2036, :score=>2},
  #    {:name=>"Ariel Jacobson"   , :elo=>2015, :score=>3},
  #    {:name=>"Dovie Emmerich"   , :elo=>2383, :score=>4},
  #    {:name=>"Helen Douglas"    , :elo=>2352, :score=>4}]
```

We already know the scores sum to 15. As

```
a.map { |h| h[:elo] }.sum
  #=> 10993
```

we see that the combined ELO limit is not exceeded.

[Array#sum](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum) made its debut in Ruby v2.4.

Answer (score 3):

If the dataset is not huge, here you go (possibly quite inefficient):

```
data =
  %|Derek Aufderhar, 2134, 1
    Hadley Kuhn, 2044, 0
    Myrtie Lueilwitz, 2207, 2
    Mitchell Schiller, 2036, 2
    Javier Walter MD, 2485, 4
    Waino Leuschke, 2486, 2
    Ariel Jacobson, 2015, 3
    Melvin Bailey, 2485, 0
    Dovie Emmerich, 2383, 4
    Adrian Stroman Jr., 2180, 1
    Helen Douglas, 2352, 4
    Yessenia O’Reilly, 2247, 2|

# unnecessary: transform to hash for clarity
values =
  data.
    split($/).
    map { |e| e.split(',') }.
    map { |name, elo, score| {name: name, elo: elo.to_i, score: score.to_i } }

# find the top
values.
  combination(5).
  reject { |data| data.map { |e| e[:elo] }.inject(:+) > 11_000 }.
  max { |data| data.map { |e| e[:score] }.inject(:+) }
#⇒ [{:name=>"Yessenia O'Reilly", :elo=>2247, :score=>2},
#   {:name=>"Helen Douglas", :elo=>2352, :score=>4},
#   {:name=>"Adrian Stroman Jr.", :elo=>2180, :score=>1},
#   {:name=>"Ariel Jacobson", :elo=>2015, :score=>3},
#   {:name=>"Mitchell Schiller", :elo=>2036, :score=>2}]
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea, I optimize it very much and it works for datasets up to 200 records. I would post the answer for the rest but for another time the majority of stackoverflow community knows everything and it doesn't need my answer for this.